# Is there a faster way to calculate a pseudo-inverse of a matrix than using SVD that is as numerically stable as with SVD?

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Is there a faster way to calculate a pseudo-inverse of a matrix than using SVD that is as numerically stable as using SVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the dominant term in the pseudo-inverse is the smallest nonzero singular value of the matrix, this would require stably producing the singular values (or approximate singular values) of the matrix. While this can be done without doing the full SVD, it can never be as stable, since any error in the smallest singular value would lead to large errors in the pseudoinverse.

I should note that there *are* ways to calculate the pseudoinverse without the SVD, if you know additional structure. For example, if $A$ is invertible, the pseudoinverse is the inverse, so you can just use LU factorization. Or if $A$ has full column rank, then you could use the QR factorization.

Comment: The only thing guaranteed in my problem is that the matrix is rectangular. Whether it is full-rank or not, it is impossible to say before doing some calculation, probably the SVD itself.

Comment: Another property of my matrix is that it is MxN, M > 2N.

Comment: Comparing left pseudo-inverse with the pseudo-inverse from SVD, SVD is more stable.

Comment: QR factorization worked fine, I followed this [link](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/05-ls.pdf). I am in doubt if it is really needed to transpose Q and calculate the inverse of R.

Comment: Good to know. But note that in QR factorization is only going to work if $A$ has full rank.

Comment: @davips If you need only to multiply the pseudo-inverse with a vector, you most likely do not need to compute it explicitly using QR or SVD.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Unfortunatelly, I need the pseudoinverse for Recursive LEast Squares among other things :(